# Parsing a Json Twitter response in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I'm using the twit module to search twitter for all tweets containing the a specific word

```
T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-11-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Now I need to parse the data that I received and I have some doubt.
You can see the data in this image.

[image]

How can I split every tweet and load them in an array? I also need only some info about a tweet for example the **text** attribute and the **name** of the user (that I cannot see through the attributes list... someone can tell me why?) .

What I try to do without success is to access to the text attribute in this why

```
tweets.statuses[0].metadata.text
```

Comment: try `tweets.statuses[0].text`

Comment: Nice! It works... but what is metadata inside the []?
How can I get the name of the user that post the comment?

Comment: i don't know, how you get this result. in node-twitter user - {}. and `tweets.statuses[0].user.screen_name`. try change `console.log(data)` to `console.log(util.inspect(data, false, Infinity, true));`

Answer (score 0):

To split each tweet and load them in an array, you'll probably be best looping over each item and setting the values to values of a collection that can represent each tweet. For example, I'd use an array object to represent a tweet and store each key value pair in the array. Something like this should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tweets.statuses.count; i++){

    var tweet = [];
    tweet[i+1] = {
       id:tweets.statuses[i].id, 
       text:tweets.statuses[i].text,  
       //etc
    };

    tweetsArray[i] = tweet[i+1];

 };
```

You should end up with an array of tweets, each tweet being a collection in itself.